# Lagged auto-correlations of numpy.random.normal not nul

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am struggling with an unexpected/unwanted behavior of the function [random.normal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) of numpy.

By generating vectors of T elements with this function, I find that in average the lagged auto-correlation of those vectors in not 0 at lags different than 0. The auto-correlation value tends to -1/(T-1).

See for example this simple code:

```
import numpy as np

N        = 10000000
T        = 100
invT     = -1./(T-1.)
sd       = 1
av       = 0
mxlag    = 10

X        = np.random.normal(av, sd, size=(N, T))
acf      = X[:,0:mxlag+1]
for i in range(N):
    acf[i,:] = [1. if l==0 else np.corrcoef(X[i,l:],X[i,:-l])[0][1] for l in range(mxlag+1)]

acf_mean = np.average(acf, axis=0)

print('mean auto-correlation of random_normal vector of length T=',T,' : ',acf_mean)
print('to be compared with -1/(T-1) = ',invT)
```

I have this behavior with both those version of Python: v2.7.9 and v3.7.4. Also, codding this in [NCL](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/) gives me the same result.

The problem I am referring to might seem tiny. However, it leads to larger biases when those vectors are used as seeds to generate auto-regressive time series. This is also problematic in case one uses this function to create bootstrap statistical tests.

Someone would have an explanation about this? Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Link to the related NCL issue I opened: https://github.com/NCAR/ncl/issues/189

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not a shortcoming of the function. My problem is coming from the bias in the estimate of the sample auto-correlation. This has been documented back in 1954...

Reference: Marriott, F. H. C., and J. A. Pope. "Bias in the estimation of autocorrelations." Biometrika 41.3/4 (1954): 390-402 (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2332719)